# Having custom widgets inside Dojo Select widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

This is the way we create dojo `Select` widgets programatically:

```
require(["dijit/form/Select", "dojo/_base/window", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Select, win){
    new Select({
        name: "select2",
        options: [
            { label: "TN", value: "Tennessee" },
            { label: "VA", value: "Virginia", selected: true },
            { label: "WA", value: "Washington" },
            { label: "FL", value: "Florida" },
            { label: "CA", value: "California" }
        ]
    }).placeAt(win.body());
});
```

Is it allowed to have custom widgets in place of `value`(which is basically a string)?

For example, in dojo grids, we can return custom widgets inside formatters. Do we have something similar to that in select widgets?

Answer (score 0):

You can "style" select. Just look at the [docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/form/Select.html#a-styled-select)